# apt-get update error: Unable to find expected entry  contrib/source/Sources in Meta-index file

Tags: 10.10, apt, official-repositories

I've made a horrible mistake and removed gtk (and all linked packets, including gnome). After that, I've recovered my GUI with 
`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` and most of key packets, but now I'm getting error when i'm trying to do `sudo apt-get update`:

```
Hit http://repo.yandex.ru maverick Release.gpg
Hit http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com maverick Release.gpg
Ign http://repo.yandex.ru/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Ign http://repo.yandex.ru/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://repo.yandex.ru/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-ru
Ign http://repo.yandex.ru/ubuntu/ maverick/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/contrib Translation-ru
Ign http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Ign http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-ru
Ign http://repo.yandex.ru/ubuntu/ maverick/non-free Translation-en_US
Ign http://repo.yandex.ru/ubuntu/ maverick/non-free Translation-ru
Hit http://repo.yandex.ru maverick Release                 
Ign http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/restricted Translation-en_US
Hit http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/restricted Translation-ru
Hit http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com maverick Release                                
Hit http://repo.yandex.ru maverick/main i386 Packages      
Hit http://repo.yandex.ru maverick/non-free i386 Packages
Hit http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources
W: Failed to fetch http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/Release  Unable to find expected entry  contrib/source/Sources in Meta-index file (malformed Release file?)

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've issued `sudo apt-get clean all` and it changed nothing.

`/etc/apt/sources.list` looks like:

```
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main contrib restricted  
deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main contrib restricted  
deb http://repo.yandex.ru/ubuntu/ maverick main non-free
```

`sudo apt-get update` works fine without `contrib` in deb records

**Is there any way to fix to that problem?**

I am using ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: you should not have `contrib` in your standard deb entries - why have you got that in the sources file?  generally that is for third party repos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`contrib` is not a valid section for the official ubuntu mirrors, hence the cryptic message that `contrib/source/Sources` cannot be found.

`repo.yandex.ru` is not an official one listed at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors. The `non-free` section of that mirror does not contain any binaries nor sources. If you want to use the Yandex mirror, use [`mirror.yandex.ru`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/mirror.yandex.ru).

Furthermore, your repository sources list is missing `security.ubuntu.com` which may cause delayed security updates.

You to should set your repository sources to at least:

```
deb http://ru.archive.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted
deb-src http://ru.archive.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main-security restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main-security restricted
```

You're missing a lot packages with this list, I recommend you to use the list which was provided on a new installation, save the below text as `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted
deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick universe
deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick universe
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates universe
deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick multiverse
deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick multiverse
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates multiverse
deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security multiverse
```